# How can I make my table move more realistically after a collision?

Tags: unity, physics

Using Unity 2020.

I have a character using CharacterController and Rigidbody, colliding into the end of a long table.

My table has, as a root object, the mesh and the Rigidbody.
It also has, as child objects, 5 box colliders (4 for the feet, and 1 for the table).

The problem is that when the character collides into the table on one end, the whole table translate in the same direction as the character's travel direction.

But I want the table to move more realistically: I want it to behave like on the right:

[image]

What could be the problem there, and how do I fix it?