# Motion of a cube after it bounces off a floor

Tags: physics, collision-resolution, rigidbody, simulations, motion

I am trying to simulate what happens when a cube hits the floor after free fall. I am considering a situation in which cube hits the floor with its edge. There is obviously reaction force from the floor which gives the cube some angular velocity but then also some translational velocity. How to calculate this distribution of energy between rotational and translational kinetic energies? Let's assume that there are no losses during the collision so total energy should be the same. I was thinking about decomposing the force from the floor into a component paralel with the line connecting the edge touching the ground and center of mass of the cube and a component perpendicular to this line. By doing so I would not get good distribution of energy, meaning sine and cosine would not add up to one unless they are squared. This is where I am now. Does anyone know how to do this? How to resolve this kind of collision?

Comment: Linked: [Transferring linear momentum to angular momentum in Godot](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/203240/transferring-linear-momentum-to-angular-momentum-in-godot).

Comment: Great book that will give you all you need to do physics for game development:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/game-physics-engine/9780123819765/

Source code for the physics engine is here: https://github.com/idmillington/cyclone-physics

If you parse through all of that it should give you what you need to make the calculations you want.

Comment: well thank you but that would be too much help, I am not trying to just copy paste something but to write my own.

Comment: Regarding book, thank you, it is good.